# Add the date of the order after the ID

Tags: 7, commerce

how do I add the order date after the order ID ?

Here is the contents of my file "commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php" :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Template for invoiced orders.
 */

?>

<?php
//The code to get payment type

$order_id = $content['commerce_customer_billing']['#object']->order_id;

$payment_method = '';
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$r = explode('|', $order->data['payment_method']);

if (count($r) > 1){
  $rule = rules_config_load($r[1]);
  $payment_method = $rule->label;
}
?>

<div class="invoice-invoiced">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="<?php print $content['invoice_logo']['#value']; ?>"/>
    <div class="invoice-header">
        <p><?php print render($content['invoice_header']); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <div class="customer-billing"><?php print render($content['commerce_customer_billing']); ?></div>
  <div class="customer-shipping"><?php print render($content['commerce_customer_shipping']); ?></div> 
  <div class="invoice-number"><?php print render($content['order_number']); ?></div>
  <div class="invoice-header-date"><?php print render($content['invoice_header_date']); ?></div>
  <div class="order-id"><?php print render($content['order_id']); ?></div>
  <div class="invoice-header-date"><?php print render($content['invoice_header_date']); ?></div>

  <div class="line-items">
    <div class="line-items-view"><?php print render($content['commerce_line_items']); ?></div>
    <div class="order-total"><?php print render($content['commerce_order_total']); ?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="invoice-text"><?php print render($content['invoice_text']); ?></div>
  <?php print("Mode de règlement : " .$payment_method); ?>

  <div class="invoice-footer"><?php print render($content['invoice_footer']); ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you already loaded the order, I guess you could do:

```
<div class="order-id">
  <?php print render($content['order_id']); ?>
  <?php print format_date($order->created, 'custom', 'd-m-Y'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. The date is displayed as mer, 29/03/2017 - 13:48 How to display it in this format 29-03-2017 ?

Comment: You can pass a second argument to format_date specifying a date format from Drupal.

Comment: I do not know the PHP language. Can you tell me who to write ?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7.x

Comment: The date must be in this format d-m-Y how to insert it in the code above ? thank you

Comment: I updated the answer.